# Angularjs bootstrap tooltip is not working properly

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using **AngularJS** bootstrap tooltip. tooltip placement by default it is taking top. If I set the placement as "top", "bottom", "right", " left" it is working as per the selected value.

For My Case :

1. I need tooltip only for `left` and `right`.
2. If I set right, when it will reach end of rightside in screen, the tooltip is hiding.
3. Same as if i select as "left", when it will first in left hand side, that particular tooltip is hiding.
4. My requirement is, If it will reach right edge, automatically it should come left, same as left side also.
5. If I come down, it should visible on top, same as top also.
6. The conclusion is , it should be auto responsive.

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview)

**js/angular:**

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('PopoverDemoCtrl', function ($scope, $sce) {
  $scope.dynamicPopover = {
    content: 'Hello, World!',
    templateUrl: 'myPopoverTemplate.html',
    title: 'Title'
  };

  $scope.placement = {
    options: [
      'top',
      'top-left',
      'top-right',
      'bottom',
      'bottom-left',
      'bottom-right',
      'left',
      'left-top',
      'left-bottom',
      'right',
      'right-top',
      'right-bottom'
    ],
    selected: 'top'
  };

  $scope.htmlPopover = $sce.trustAsHtml('<b style="color: red">I can</b> have <div class="label label-success">HTML</div> content');
});
```

**Html:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.5.0.js"></script>
    <script src="example.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>

<div ng-controller="PopoverDemoCtrl">
    <h4>Dynamic</h4>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Popup Text:</label>
      <input type="text" ng-model="dynamicPopover.content" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Popup Title:</label>
      <input type="text" ng-model="dynamicPopover.title" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Popup Template:</label>
      <input type="text" ng-model="dynamicPopover.templateUrl" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <button uib-popover="{{dynamicPopover.content}}" popover-title="{{dynamicPopover.title}}" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Dynamic Popover</button>

    <button uib-popover-template="dynamicPopover.templateUrl" popover-title="{{dynamicPopover.title}}" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Popover With Template</button>

    <script type="text/ng-template" id="myPopoverTemplate.html">
        <div>{{dynamicPopover.content}}</div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Popup Title:</label>
          <input type="text" ng-model="dynamicPopover.title" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </script>
    <hr />
    <h4>Positional</h4>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Popover placement</label>
      <select class="form-control" ng-model="placement.selected" ng-options="o as o for o in placement.options"></select>
    </div>
    <button popover-placement="{{placement.selected}}" uib-popover="On the {{placement.selected}}" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Popover {{placement.selected}}</button>

    <hr />
    <h4>Triggers</h4>
    <p>
      <button uib-popover="I appeared on mouse enter!" popover-trigger="'mouseenter'" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Mouseenter</button>
    </p>
    <input type="text" value="Click me!" uib-popover="I appeared on focus! Click away and I'll vanish..."  popover-trigger="'focus'" class="form-control">

    <hr />
    <h4>Other</h4>
    <button popover-animation="true" uib-popover="I fade in and out!" type="button" class="btn btn-default">fading</button>
    <button uib-popover="I have a title!" popover-title="The title." type="button" class="btn btn-default">title</button>
    <button uib-popover="I am activated manually" popover-is-open="popoverIsOpen" ng-click="popoverIsOpen = !popoverIsOpen" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Toggle popover</button>
    <button uib-popover-html="htmlPopover" class="btn btn-default">HTML Popover</button>
    <button uib-popover-html="'<b>HTML</b>, <i>inline</i>'" class="btn btn-default">HTML Popover (inline)</button>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Can anyone please help me how can I do this?

Comment: popover-placement="right left"

Comment: You would have to write your own tooltip directive. You can see this same hiding behavior on the demo page: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#tooltip